# Why does Rolls Royce have 4 separate tickers, on OTC Markets?

Tags: stocks

I found at least 4 tickers for Rolls Royce

1. RLLCF. This is Preferred Share? The others are Common Shares?
2. RYCEY
3. RYCEF
4. RYCRF

What are the differences? Are there any more for the US stock market? I ignore RR.L because it's traded on the London Stock Exchange.

I live in the US. I don't want to convert my USD to GBP just to invest in Rolls Royce.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll start with RYCEY and leave RLLCF for last.

- [RYCEY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RYCEY/overview) — This is an American Depositary Receipt (ADR). In the US, 5-letter tickers that end with "Y" are ADRs. This is a *sponsored* ADR. According to the [Rolls Royce investors FAQ](https://www.rolls-royce.com/investors/shareholder-information/faqs.aspx):

  > Which Stock Exchange is the Company listed on?
  >
  > The Company is listed on the London Stock Exchange. The Company's ticker symbol is RR. Rolls-Royce Ordinary Shares are also traded "over the counter" in the United States in the form of a sponsored American Depositary Receipt (ADR) facility with J.P. Morgan as the depositary. Each ADR represents one Ordinary Share.

  You can get more information about this ADR from J.P. Morgan's website: https://adr.com/drprofile/775781206. On that web page, you will be able to see the historical dividends and ADR fees.

  The maximum fees are mentioned in the "deposit agreement" in the [Form F-6 filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1474274/000119380515001291/e613959_ex99-a.htm) available in EDGAR. The fees can be found in Exhibit A, section 7 "Charges of Depositary".
- [RYCEF](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RYCEF/overview) — This is an "F share" (the 5-letter ticker ends with "F"). US broker-dealers created this ticker to provide US investors with quotes of Rolls Royce in US dollars instead of British Pounds. This represents US over-the-counter market quotes of Rolls Royce's London Stock Exchange shares. More details about F shares: [FAQ on F Shares - OTC Markets](https://www.otcmarkets.com/files/FAQ-on-Ordinary-Shares.pdf)
- RYCRF — According to FINRA's [OTC Daily List](https://otce.finra.org/otce/dailyList), this is "ROLLS-ROYCE HOLDINGS PLC, LONDON ORD GBP0.2 NPD 11 11 20 Rights 11/11/2020" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjGJ0.png)). It was added on 30 October 2020, and removed on 11 November 2020. It is no longer traded.

  It was an F share that represented a rights issue that closed on 11 November 2020. Information about this rights issue from London Stock Exchange's Regulatory News Service (RNS):

  - [Proposed Recapitalisation](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/RR./proposed-recapitalisation/14704841) (dated 1 October 2020)
  - [Publication of a Prospectus](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/RR./publication-of-a-prospectus/14705778) (dated 1 October 2020)
  - [Result of Rights Issue](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/RR./result-of-rights-issue/14752926) (dated 12 November 2020)
- [RLLCF](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RLLCF/overview) — This is an F share representing Rolls Royce's "C Shares". According to the [2019 shareholder guide](https://www.rolls-royce.com/%7E/media/files/R/Rolls-Royce/documents/investors/shareholder-guide-2019.pdf):

  > What are C Shares?
  >
  > C Share are non-cumulative redeemable preference shares of 0.1p each in the capital of Rolls-Royce that can, during defined periods, be redeemed for cash. Rolls-Royce will generally issue C Shares to all ordinary shareholders twice a year in lieu of a cash dividend. C Shares should not be confused with your Ordinary Shares.

  Note that there has recently been some changes to C Shares, so the quote above is probably outdated. Refer to [Payments to shareholders — C Share issues](https://www.rolls-royce.com/investors/shareholder-information/payments-to-shareholders/home/content/section/c-share-issues.aspx) for updated information about the C Shares. I don't know where/when the change was first announced, but I found a mention of the change in a [press release](https://www.rolls-royce.com/%7E/media/Files/R/Rolls-Royce/documents/investors/2020-hy-press-release.pdf) dated 27 August 2020 (see section "Payments to shareholders" on page 50).