# How does BYDDF differ from BYDDY?

Tags: stocks

1. How does BYDDF differ from BYDDY?

I don't understand this forum post – ["BYDDY is a sponsored ADR. BYDDF is traded on Hong Kong Stock Exchange."](https://www.cornerofberkshireandfairfax.ca/forum/general-discussion/buying-byd-in-us/)

When I Googled this, I saw ["ARKQ (ETF) is holding BYD/BYDDF. a decent size positon."](https://old.reddit.com/r/stocks/comments/jofcbz/why_is_no_one_talking_about_byd_here/gbavili)

2. When ["I viewed all holdings"](https://ark-funds.com/wp-content/fundsiteliterature/holdings/ARK_AUTONOMOUS_TECHNOLOGY_&_ROBOTICS_ETF_ARKQ_HOLDINGS.pdf) on [ARKQ](https://ark-funds.com/arkq), I see BYDDY listed as UNsponsored. What does "UNsponsored" and "sponsored" mean?

Comment: ""BYDDY is a sponsored ADR. BYDDF is traded on Hong Kong Stock Exchange" — Where did that quote come from? I don't see that quote anywhere in the forum thread you linked to.

Comment: [Sponsored ADR](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sponsoredadr.asp) vs [unsponsored ADR](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/unsponsoredadr.asp)

Comment: [ADRs](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/general-resources/news-alerts/alerts-bulletins/investor-bulletins-88) vs [F shares](https://www.otcmarkets.com/files/FAQ-F-Shares.pdf)

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/133423 very good explanation