# Would I have to personally pay UK taxes on any profits on Rolls Royce RYCEF stock?

Tags: stocks

I have read [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/133425/87052) and [this webpage](https://www.schwab.com/stocks/understand-stocks/adrs-foreign-ordinaries-canadian-stocks) by Schwab; however, I am still a bit confused by the RYCEF Rolls Royce stock.

Looking at the table on the Schwab page, is RYCEF a 'foreign ordinary traded in the over-the-counter (OTC) market', or is it a 'foreign ordinary traded on local exchanges overseas'?

I am also a bit confused about the potential tax implications of investing in this stock, as a US investor. Would I have to personally pay UK taxes on any profits?

Answer (score 1):

It's a foreign ordinary traded in the OTC market. You're not able to place online trades for foreign ordinaries traded on local exchanges overseas, but you can for RYCEF.

Country-specific, but in general, you'll pay the required taxes in the foreign country (if any) and then can claim the [foreign tax credit](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-tax-credit) for eligible foreign taxes paid so the income isn't subject to double-taxation here in the US. Here's an [Investopedia article](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/012214/understanding-taxation-foreign-investments.asp) on the foreign tax credit too.

Comment: Ok, this is very helpful, thanks. So, I would need to file a tax return in the UK if I bought RYCEF through, say, Fidelity?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I know with mutual funds and ETFs you generally don't have to - your 1099 shows taxes Fidelity withheld to pay to foreign governments. There could be differences with individual foreign stocks traded OTC (like RYCEF) or directly on local overseas exchanges.

Comment: ok, thanks very much again for your advice! I will check into how the tax would work with Fidelity.

Comment: FYI: I checked with Fidelity and they said tax on foreign stocks is generally charged by the foreign government on *transactions*, i.e. on initial purchase or dividends. So, shouldn't be any need to submit a foreign return myself, although those taxes might be claimable as US tax deductions.